# Number of Accessible Class and Method [ARCore]

Tags: class, methods, arcore, accessible

I am interested in learning the number of classes that can be used with ARCore, as well as the number of methods that can be accessed for each class (regardless of the operating system).

1. The total number of accessible classes
2. The total number of accessible methods